# Growth rate of $(\log{n})^{3n}$ and $(n)^{\frac{n}{3}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

To find the growth rate of $(\log{n})^{3n}$ and $(n)^{\frac{n}{3}}$, I took the log of both:

1. $(\log{n})^{3n}$:

$$\log (\log{n})^{3n} = 3n \log{\log{n}} \in O(n \log n)$$

but the answer I have says it's $O(n)$.

2. $(n)^{\frac{n}{3}}$:

$$\log (n)^{\frac{n}{3}} =\frac{n}{3} \log{n} \in O(n \log n) $$

also the answer I have says it's  $O(n)$.

What do you think please?

Comment: I'm confused, aren't both of those at least exponential?

Comment: I think you confused yourself on the first simply in setup ...

Comment: I am confused as you. This is how I solved them, but both solution say they have linear time

Comment: How can they be linear if they are at least exponential ? clearly both are at least $2^n$ for $n\geq 8$.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the *log* of the times has linear time?

Comment: why are you taking the log of those to get the growth rates?

Comment: The log of the first one is $O(n\log(\log(n)))$ and that is a subset of $O(n\log(n))$, but neither is a subset of $O(n)$.

Comment: @robjohn. I had this solution before, so I tried to solve it again. I took the log to of both $2^n$ and pf $(\log{n})^{3n}$, so it won't affect probably the final growth rate?

Comment: $a_n$ and $\log(a_n)$ have quite different growth rates, so taking the log will affect the final growth rate. What is true is that if $\log(a_n)$ has a slower growth rate than $\log(b_n)$ then $a_n$ will also have a slower growth rate than $b_n$.